# Deleting login credentials and history from WPF webview2 cache in C# .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, webview2

Clear the cache memory of webview2 WPF while runtime

I am trying to delete the cache memory stored by WPF webview2, I am defining the userfolder but not finding any proper method to delete the userfolder.
I don't want to dispose the webview2 as it will loose some other information apart from cache memory
I just want to delete the login credentials and history of webview2

```
     async void WebFullSCreenInitialize()
        {
            string browseExe = exePath + "\\Microsoft.WebView2";
            string cacheFolder = exePath + "\\Cache";
            var op = new CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions("--disable-web-security ; --autoplay-          policy=no-user-gesture-required");
            var env = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(browseExe, cacheFolder, op);
            await externalWebFullSCreen.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(env);


          
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WPF you can clear the cache folder create by Webview2 at runtime. On specific event just call a method

```
public Void clearCacheWebview() 
{
 externalWebFullSCreen.CoreWebView2.Profile.ClearBrowsingDataAsync();
 externalWebFullSCreen.Source = new URI("your url after clearing thecache");
}
```

Make sure you are using the latest webview version as CoreWebView2.Profile.ClearBrowsingDataAsync is available to latest version.